# Eigenvalues of self-adjoint eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, eigenfunctions

I am stack with the following problem:
Consider the following eigenvalue problem $$ u \in H_B(0,1), \; \langle Lu, Lv\rangle = \lambda (\alpha \langle u, v\rangle + \langle u', v'\rangle) \; \forall v\in H_B(0,1),$$
where 
$$H_B(0,1) = \begin{cases}
 \{u \in H^2(0,1): u(0) = u(1) = 0\},&\text{if}\quad B = 0,\\
 \\
 \{u \in H^2(0,1): u'(0) = u'(1) = 0\},& \text{if}\quad B = 1,
         \end{cases} $$
$$Lu:= -du'' + cu, \; d>0, \;c\in C[0,1] $$ and $$\alpha>0.$$ 
I need to show that the spectrum of the problem above consists of eigenvalues which are real and converge to infinity.

My initial thought was it to use the spectral theorem for the compact self-adjoint operators. After rewriting the problem above in strong formulation as
\begin{equation}
L^\ast L u = \lambda (\alpha u + u''), \; u \in \tilde{H}_B(0,1), 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tilde{H}_B(0,1) = \begin{cases}
 \{u \in H^4(0,1): u(0) = u(1) = 0\},&\text{if}\quad B = 0,\\
 \\
 \{u \in H^4(0,1): u'(0) = u'(1) = 0\},& \text{if}\quad B = 1,
         \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
I wanted to show that the operator $(L^\ast L + \sigma I)^{-1}$ is compact and self-adjoint. If this is the case, then from the spectral theorem one can conclude that there exists the orthonormal basis $\varphi_k$ of $L^2(0,1)$ of the eigenfunctions of $(L^\ast L  + \sigma I)^{-1}$ and the corresponding sequence of eigenvalues $\mu_k$ is real and converges to $0$.

Honestly, I don't really know how to proceed with this problem further and would appreciate any help and useful hints. I think, that showing self-adjointness is not problematic, but how to show compactness? I feel like I should consider an operator of the form $E(L^\ast L + \sigma I)^{-1} : L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$ where $E$ is a suitable compact embedding? Am I on the right track here? Is considering the strong formulation of the above eigenvalue problem is a good idea in general?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with spectrum? Your first equation doesn't look like an eigenvalue equation for an operator - is this something like an eigenvalue equation for the quadratic form $\langle L \cdot, L \cdot \rangle $? If so, how are the other types of spectrum defined?

Comment: Hi Roland, sorry for the belated answer. I think you are right and this is an eigenvalue equation for the quadratic form, not for the operator. At that point I have to say, that I did not really understand your question (which is probably the reason why I cannot solve this problem :)). Can you please elaborate on your question more?

Comment: Maybe it's just some confusion on the phrasing "spectrum of the problem above consists of eigenvalues" from my side: The spectrum of operators usually doesn't consist only of eigenvalues; there's also the possibility of continuous spectrum - somehow I was thinking that we need to show that as well. The operator $L$ itself has a compact resolvent and is self-adjoint - for this property the best (english) citation I can offer is J. Weidmann: Spectral Theory for Differential Operators, (1987), Theorem 7.10, which is more general than needed.

Comment: Is it obvious that the operator $L$ has a compact resolvent? Should not we consider the operator $L^\ast L$ in that case?

Comment: No, it is not obvious, but 'well-known'. I've found another citation: T. Kato, _Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators_, III.6.8 deals with operators with compact resolvents and mentions that $L$ has a compact resolvent as it's resolvent is an integral operator with a continuous kernel integrating on a compact set. See also sections III.4.1 and III.2.3, which are referenced.

Comment: Thank you for the citations! Can you probably explain why in this case we consider the operator $L$ and not $L^\ast L$? I thought since we start with the bilinear form it is not enough to show the compactness of the resolvent of $L$. Should not we try to show the compactness of the resolvent of the operator $L^\ast L$?

Comment: I'm not saying that you should consider the operator $L$ - it's just the fact that second order differential operators are far more common as examples than fourth order. I think that you should indeed consider $L^*L=L^2$. Due to the selfadjointness of $L$, it should not be too hard to conclude from $L$ to $L^2$ using a spectral mapping theorem (this is an inspired guess, not a working directive).

Comment: Well, I have to think it through by myself then. This was actually my problem at the beginning: showing that the resolvent of $L^\ast L$ is compact.